# Получить текущее время в наносекундах в C++

Tags: c++, время

Мне нужно получить текущее время (с первого января 1970 года) в C++ в наносекундах, в типе `int64_t` или `u_int64_t`. Я просмотрел много информации, но как-то всё очень запутанно и неудобно. Есть какой-нибудь простой способ это сделать в одну строчку?

Comment: В *nix-ах [clock_gettime](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) (реально же, разрешение лучше нескольких сот наносекунд (с учетом задержки самого вызова ОС) все равно не получить)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если на системе реализован посиксный интерфейс, то можно использовать `clock_gettime`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

::uint64_t
Fetch_NanosecondsTime(void)
{
#if(defined(_POSIX_TIMERS) && (0 < _POSIX_TIMERS))
    struct ::timespec time{};
    if (0 == ::clock_getres(CLOCK_REALTIME, ::std::addressof(time)))
    {
        if ((0 == time.tv_sec) && (1 == time.tv_nsec))
        {
            if (0 == ::clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ::std::addressof(time)))
            {
                assert(0 <= time.tv_sec);
                assert(0 <= time.tv_nsec);
                assert(time.tv_nsec < 1'000'000'000);
                return static_cast<::uint64_t>(time.tv_sec) * ::uint64_t{1'000'000'000}
                   + static_cast<::uint64_t>(time.tv_nsec);
            }
            else
            {
                throw ::std::runtime_error{"::clock_gettime call failed"};
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw ::std::runtime_error{"time with nanosecond resolution is not available"};
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw ::std::runtime_error{"::clock_getres call failed"};
    }
#else
#error time with nanosecond resolution is not supported
#endif
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/f76G1ooha

Comment: У меня ваш вариант стабильно выдаёт 0.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Да, там 1000000000 должно было быть. Но в остальном код рабочий.

Comment: Я уже удалил, раз вы исправили. Но у меня всё равно выводится 0.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Утверждения вида "всё равно выводится 0" следует подкреплять, приводя [mcve]. Я же привел ссылку на godbolt  - все работает.

Comment: Всё, понял. Когда копировал ваш код, забыл вызвать `clock_gettime`. Я так понимаю, эта реализация даёт наиболее точное время?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Я еще добавил проверку разрешения часов перед вызовом. В этом случае действительно можно быть уверенным, что время приходит в наносекундах. Хотя проверку наверное имеет смысл делать только один раз.

Answer (score 4):

В одну строчку, можете этот код сделать функцией.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>


int main() {
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();
  auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration);

  std::cout << nanoseconds.count() << '\n';
  std::cout << static_cast<int64_t>(nanoseconds.count()) << '\n';
  std::cout << static_cast<uint64_t>(nanoseconds.count()) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

статический метод `now` возвращает объект класса `time_point`, от этого обьекта вызываем `time_since_epoch`, который возвращает `duration`, который представляет количество времени между `*this` и эпохой часов, далее приводим `duration` в наносекунды, далее через метод `count` возвращаем наносекунды.

подробнее можно почитать здесь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono

Comment: Боже, это прекрасно! Для сравнения: в яве это выглядит так: `System.nanotime()`.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия можете написать функцию с такой же сигнатурой и все туда засунуть :))

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Этот ответ вводит в заблуждение. Хотя время в итоге выводится в наносекундах, используемые часы совсем не обязательно отдают его с наносекундным разрешением. По сути, тут получается почти такая же проблема, как и с другим ответом - `time(NULL) * 10000000000`.

Comment: @user7860670 что может быть поточнее?

Comment: А стандарт на этот счет не дает вообще никаких гарантий, даже для `high_resolution_clock`. Cледует всегда использовать что-то системно-специфическое, а `std::chrono` - только когда есть уверенность в конкретной реализации.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint64_t sec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).