# Как измерить время в МИКРОсекундах?

Tags: c++

Нашёл лишь способ с миллисекундами. Попытался сам написать с помощью этого chrono, но не понял всё что там есть. Как узнать прошедшее время в микросекундах, или наносекундах?

Comment: См. [man 7 time](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) и далее [man 2 clock_gettime](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

Comment: [Дубликат вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271560/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку с `chrono`.